# How to combine multiple series into one choosing a single nonnull value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns in a DataFrame(5000000x100) that ares sparsely non-null like so (the non null values are currency codes):

```
NaN           EUR             EUR
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
EUR           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           GBP             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
USD           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           NaN             NaN
NaN           EUR             EUR
```

I also have a dictionary with the conversion rates to Euro like so:

```
{'USD':0.8499 , 'EUR': 1 , 'GBP': 1.135}
```

I wish to create another column with the corresponding conversion rate for each row (we can assume that a single row will only have instances of a single currency) EG:

```
    NaN           EUR             EUR    1
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    EUR           NaN             NaN    1
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           GBP             NaN    1.135
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    USD           NaN             NaN    0.8499
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           NaN             NaN    NaN
    NaN           EUR             EUR    1
```

I can achieve the desired result for a single column by using map. EG:

```
res = s.map(conversion_rate_dictionary)
```

which would give for a small example:

```
s    res
NaN  NaN
EUR  1
GBP  1.135
USD  0.849
NaN  NaN
```

Im stumped as to how to get the desired result either directly or by combining the results of map on each of the columns. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `ffill` for forward filling `NaN`s and then select last column by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
d = {'USD':0.8499 , 'EUR': 1 , 'GBP': 1.135}
df['new'] = df.replace(d).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
      a    b    c     new
0   NaN  EUR  EUR  1.0000
1   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
3   EUR  NaN  NaN  1.0000
4   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
6   NaN  GBP  NaN  1.1350
7   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
9   USD  NaN  NaN  0.8499
10  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
12  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
13  NaN  EUR  EUR  1.0000
```

Detail:

```
print (df.replace(d).ffill(axis=1))
         a       b       c
0      NaN  1.0000  1.0000
1      NaN     NaN     NaN
2      NaN     NaN     NaN
3   1.0000  1.0000  1.0000
4      NaN     NaN     NaN
5      NaN     NaN     NaN
6      NaN  1.1350  1.1350
7      NaN     NaN     NaN
8      NaN     NaN     NaN
9   0.8499  0.8499  0.8499
10     NaN     NaN     NaN
11     NaN     NaN     NaN
12     NaN     NaN     NaN
13     NaN  1.0000  1.0000
```

Numpy solution is faster in large `DataFrame`:

```
d = {'USD':0.8499 , 'EUR': 1 , 'GBP': 1.135}

a = df.replace(d).values
m = ~np.isnan(a)
b = a[np.arange(m.shape[0]), m.shape[1]-m[:,::-1].argmax(1)-1]
print (b)
[ 1.         nan     nan  1.         nan     nan  1.135      nan     nan
  0.8499     nan     nan     nan  1.    ]

df['new'] = b
print (df)
      a    b    c     new
0   NaN  EUR  EUR  1.0000
1   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
3   EUR  NaN  NaN  1.0000
4   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
6   NaN  GBP  NaN  1.1350
7   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
9   USD  NaN  NaN  0.8499
10  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
12  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN
13  NaN  EUR  EUR  1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution jez, I'll have a good look at it tomorrow and try to understand it and all the functions involved and will be sure to accept it or ask for clarification...

Comment: The numpy solution has me confused but I think I'll just have to get tinkering with everything to work it out, its hard to visualise, the pandas solution though is very understandable. Thank you very much.